# facebook like button migration(og:url vs href in the like button)

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

With migration of facebook like button, the recommended approach is to point href of the like button to the Facebook Page, but keep the og:url tag on the page the same. What are the results of this:
1)Are the users going to see posted hrefs to A)the facebook page or B)the page specified in the og:url tag?
2)What url are the shares going to be counted against:A)the facebook page or B)the page specified in the og:url tag?